# how to hide navigationbar when i push from navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

how to hide top bar in **UIViewcontroller** when i push from navigation controller using
**pushViewController** ?
any help please?

Answer (score 117):

Put this code in the view controller you want to hide the navigation bar for.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

And you may also want to stick this in there, depending on your needs:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: I would like to add to the question, how to make it hide/show when the user taps towards where it is. Ie: like in the photos app.

Comment: You just put that setNavigationBarHidden call wherever you like, when you need to hide the nav bar.

Comment: @Ed Marty Can we hide the navigation bar in storyboard?

Answer (score 13):

Here's how to do it in **Swift 3**:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}
```

P.S. I found that if you set animated to `false`, a black bar appears on push. But when it is set to `true` it's smooth as silk!

Comment: Thanks! It's also useful the method hidesBottomBarWhenPushed()

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 8
May be this work around could work it

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.3;
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
        [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE animated:FALSE];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:productViewObj animated:FALSE];
        [productViewObj.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE animated:FALSE];
        [productViewObj release];
```