# UIButton --> UINavigationController --> UITableView

Tags: ios6, xcode4.6

I am having an issue when im using navigation controller. My program is laid out where I have a start screen (not in the navigation controller) and then when you press a button it sends you to the navigationController and new view.

How can I call the navigation controller from the start screen?

Comment: Put main view(start screen) in navigation controller as root view and push new view when button press(tap).

Comment: I don't want the back option that the navigation gives by default, I want it to behave like once i clicked the button the uitableviewcontroller behaves as the main screen

Comment: Oh that is an issue!, you can disable back functionality of navigation controller but it is not good solution, Ok i will think on another idea for it, hope you will get answer from others.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing a view controller will only work if the view controller pushing is contained in a navigation controller. You can try to hide the navigation bar in the pushed view controller: [how to hide navigationbar when i push from navigation controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617565/how-to-hide-when-i-push-from-navigation-controller)

If you still want to keep your structure, the possible solution would be to present the navigation controller with table view controller as a modal. You need to use the presentViewController:animated:completion: method in the start view controller:

```
[self presentViewController:theTableViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: self = UIViewController i get a compile error `No visible @interface for 'viewController' declares the selector 'pushViewController:animated`

Comment: If you want use push, you need a navigation controller, and call pushViewController from self.navigationController

Answer (score 0):

in `AppDelegate.h` class

Create a property of `UINavigationController` like:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

and in give it as a RootViewController in `AppDelegate.m` like:

```
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
```

and give it to Window like:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

Thats it!!! You are Done!!

Now you have navigationController at the root as well.

Cheers!!

Comment: in which function in the appDelegate.m should I write this code? also how do I call it when the button is clicked? and last but not least how do I return to the original main screen, Thank you

Comment: `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any problem in adding first controller to UINavigationViewController then do the following to do this just from interface builer : 
1) Select first view controller in storyboard.
2) From menubar select Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller.