# Hidden NavigationBar reappears after app enters foreground

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a `UITableViewController` inside a `navigationController`. I have code that hides the `navigationBar` (sets its `frame.origin.y` to a negative value, thereby sending it offscreen) when I scroll the `tableView`. The `navigationBar` is successfully hidden, but when I leave the app by tapping the home button and then launch the app into the foreground, the navigationBar is back with `frame.origin` at `(20, 0)` (x = 20 since the status bar is visible), and the `tableView` pushed down the screen (with `frame.origin` back to `(64, 0)` in portrait).

Any ideas on how to prevent the `navigationBar` from reappearing upon the app entering the foreground would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post you code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You didn't choose the best practise to hide navigationBar as most of "interal views" are positioned by it's superview automaticaly. The thing is that when you scroll, the navigationBar is moved off the screen...but when the app enters foreground all views are layouted (checkout UIView setNeedsLayout and layoutSubviews) and this moves the novigationBar back to it's position where it belongs to (y=0). There are few other options that you can use:

1) use UINavigationController's setNavigationBarHidden:(animated:) in viewWillAppear: and viewWillDisappear:. More info here [SO: how to hide navigationbar when i push from navigation controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1618557/923642)

2) if you want to leave the space behind the navigationBar use (in viewDidLoad or methods from #1):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0;
```

3) move your code for setting frame in method viewDidLayoutSubviews of you controller (iOS 5+). Every time you scroll in UITableViewControler layoutSubviews method is called (and viewDidLayoutSubviews too). But I wouldn't recommend this solution.

Comment: Sometime we do need to customize the animation, in which case setNavigationBarHidden:animated: does not provide the functionality to do so

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the frame you can use the below code to hide the Navigation bar.

```
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

Hope this will help you. Happy coding :)