# Pushing between 2 ViewControllers - NavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to push from one VC to another - which is 0 problem, but VC1 has a orange NavigationBar while VC2 has a completely transparent NavigationBar. I would like to transition smoothly between the 2 different NavigationBars during the push segue. However, at the moment - it comes this blackish sliding bar and the color isn't transitioning nicely. This is my code:

VC1 viewWillAppear:

```
    // Set the BarTintColor to translucent and text colors to white
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
}];
```

VC 2 viewWillAppear:

```
    // Make the NavigationBar transparent
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}];
```

How can I solve this in a more efficient and better way?

Thanks!
Erik

Comment: this problem is a pain in the ass.  really I think the best solution is just to slide in the new one ("over" the old one)

Comment: @JoeBlow A solution would be to switch to modally present it instead of pushing it. What do you think is the best solution?

Comment: FTR did you try this . . http://stackoverflow.com/a/1618557/294884

Comment: @JoeBlow Tried, but you just don't get that "premium feel" with that solution :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
    // Make the NavigationBar transparent
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:.8 initialSpringVelocity:1.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

Setting the clearColor outside of the animateWithDuration block made the animation a billion times smoother. Now it animates nicely away

Comment: @JoeBlow Wouldn't another solution be to make the NavigationBar transparent at all times, and set the NavigationBar's tint using a background ImageView rather than the tint property? Perhaps that would achieve an even smoother animation? I'll try to implement that tomorrow

Comment: Hi Erik - yea, that does seem like a pretty good idea.  We're really sort of "fighting apple" on this: they will/are clearly making small change after small change to "how those bars work" on each new ios update; it's gonna be tricky to really keep it working!  :O  But yeah that seems like a nice idea...

Comment: what if you made an orange image, set the height of it according to the size of the NavigationBar and set a Constraint with 0 space to the top SuperView? And a scale-to-fill mode, would that work? @JoeBlow

Comment: @JoeBlow do you have an idea on how to put a UIImageView behind the NavigationBar?

Comment: I'm afraid I DO NOT; I'd ask another question on that