# navigationbar hidden unexpected?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

here is my question gif:
[question GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBH73.gif)
i use this code in my first VC

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    print("VC1 viewWillAppear")   
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    print("VC1 viewWillDisappear")
}
```

it refers to [how to hidden when push to a vc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617565/how-to-hide-navigationbar-when-i-push-from-navigation-controller/1618557#1618557)

Comment: What's the problem, your code is doing correctly as in your GIF? If you want to hide nav bar in second VC then put that code in your second VC

Comment: you see ,when i pop vc2 to vc1 ,and canceled this action, vc2's navigationbar   is missed

Comment: Then in VC2's `viewWillAppear:` put the `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)`, this make sure it will appear even if u cancel

Comment: i forget to say that i have already add that .   but this question is also here

Comment: Actually when u cancel the pop gesture, it will call `viewWillAppear:` again in your VC2... i wonder why it not working also

Comment: You reproduce this behavior with simulator or on a real device?

Comment: @ReinierMelian yes .it happens in simulator and real device too.
this question is same with the comment by fabb in Alan's answer .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845583/iphone-hide-navigation-bar-only-on-first-page/2406167#2406167